# Import only functions from a python file

Tags: python

I have many Python files (submission1.py, submission2.py, ... , submissionN.py) in the following format,

```
#submission1.py
def fun():
   print('some fancy function')

fun()
```

I want to write a tester to test these submissions. (They are actually homeworks that I am grading.). I have a tester for the `fun()` which is able to test the function itself. However, my problem is, when I import `submission.py`, it runs the `fun()` since it calls it at the end of file.

I know that, using `if __name__ == "__main__":` is the correct way of handling this issue, however, our submissions does not have it since we did not teach it.

So, my question is, is there any way that I can import only `fun()` from the `submission.py` files without running the rest of the python file?

Comment: No. But you can check the output from the script.

Comment: I imagine you could fairly easily use ast.parse to modify the code to remove the functions calls

Comment: If for any reason you do not want to use `if __name__ == "__main__":`, then you should **not** call `fun` at the end of the script.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, The problem is there are many submission files I have in this format now. I do not want to go over all of them and add `if __name__ == "__main__":` manually. And I don't want to write a script by myself to remove the last line in the given Python file, because there are multiple functions in the file and some function calls are in the middle of two functions.

Comment: @celebisait right, but for future semesters . . .

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, I want to test the functions with different parameters. Python scripts are not taking any command line parameters that I can send to the functions.

Comment: @celebisait can't you write some code that reads the files and rewrites them without the function call?  and then run your tester on those new files?

Comment: @celebisait Do all of the programs contain a function called `fun`. If so we could try to help you create another program to insert the main conditions.

Comment: @dbliss That makes sense, however I was expecting there would be an easier way of doing this. Because it is not only removing the last line. I may check the indentation to only find the functions.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yes, every submission has the same consistent function name.

Comment: Unfortunately the way a module is imported is by running each line of the file. When it runs `def fun():` it creates a function.

Comment: *Don't do this.* This will bring nothing but pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For simple scripts with just functions the following will work:

*submission1.py*:

```
def fun(x):
   print(x)

fun("foo")


def fun2(x):
   print(x)


fun2("bar")

print("debug print")
```

You can remove all bar the FunctionDef nodes then recompile:

```
import ast
import types

with open("submission1.py") as f:
   p = ast.parse(f.read())

for node in p.body[:]:
    if not isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        p.body.remove(node)



module = types.ModuleType("mod")
code = compile(p, "mod.py", 'exec')
sys.modules["mod"] = module
exec(code,  module.__dict__)

import mod

mod.fun("calling fun")
mod.fun2("calling fun2")
```

Output:

```
calling fun
calling fun2
```

The module body contains two Expr and one Print node which we remove in the loop keeping just the FunctionDef's.

```
[<_ast.FunctionDef object at 0x7fa33357f610>, <_ast.Expr object at 0x7fa330298a90>, 
<_ast.FunctionDef object at 0x7fa330298b90>, <_ast.Expr object at 0x7fa330298cd0>,
 <_ast.Print object at 0x7fa330298dd0>]
```

So after the loop out body only contains the functions:

```
[<_ast.FunctionDef object at 0x7f49a786a610>, <_ast.FunctionDef object at 0x7f49a4583b90>]
```

This will also catch where the functions are called with print which if the student was calling the function from an IDE where the functions have return statements is pretty likely, also to keep any imports of there are any you can keep ast.Import's and ast.ImportFrom's:

submission.py:

```
from math import *
import datetime

def fun(x):
    print(x)


fun("foo")


def fun2(x):
    return x

def get_date():
    print(pi)
    return datetime.datetime.now()
fun2("bar")

print("debug print")

print(fun2("hello world"))

print(get_date())
```

Compile then import:

```
for node in p.body[:]:
    if not isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef,ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom)):
        p.body.remove(node)
.....

import mod

mod.fun("calling fun")
print(mod.fun2("calling fun2"))
print(mod.get_date())
```

Output:

```
calling fun
calling fun2
3.14159265359
2015-05-09 12:29:02.472329
```

Lastly if you have some variables declared that you need to use you can keep them using ast.Assign:

submission.py:

```
from math import *
import datetime

AREA = 25
WIDTH = 35

def fun(x):
    print(x)


fun("foo")


def fun2(x):
    return x

def get_date():
    print(pi)
    return datetime.datetime.now()
fun2("bar")

print("debug print")

print(fun2("hello world"))

print(get_date()
```

Add ast.Assign:

```
for node in p.body[:]:
    if not isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef,
        ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom,ast.Assign)):
        p.body.remove(node)
....
```

Output:

```
calling fun
calling fun2
3.14159265359
2015-05-09 12:34:18.015799
25
35
```

So it really all depends on how your modules are structured and what they should contain as to what you remove. If there are literally only functions then the first example will do what you want. If there are other  parts that need to be kept it is just a matter of adding them to the isinstance check.

The listing of all the abstract grammar definitions is in the cpython source under [Parser/Python.asdl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/Python.asdl).

Comment: How would you also able to have import statements in submission1.py, which will going to be executed?

Comment: @celebisait: instead of removing all nodes that are not `FunctionDef`s, you can remove all nodes which are an `Expr` which value is a `Call`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, That will leave prints etc.. which I imagine the OP does not want, removing all but FunctionDef's will make sure there are only functions left.

Comment: Task was, basically, "keep functions only" - so I think it is better to only keep FunctionDefs, as it is more verbose. Anyway, that is really neat answer.

Comment: @FilipMalczak, yep cheers, you can completely control what you want to keep or remove with ast, you can remove prints from the functions etc.. add lines. ast gives you complete control over the code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, [thanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey/303350#303350) :-).

Comment: @Sait, you are very welcome, imaginary internet reputation is great and all but  getting  feedback like that is a lot more valuable and makes it all worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sys.settrace()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to catch function definitions.

Whenever your `fun()` is defined, you save it somewhere, and you place a stub into the module you are importing, so that it won't get executed.

Assuming that `fun()` gets defined only once, this code should do the trick:

```
import sys

fun = None

def stub(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def wait_for_fun(frame, event, arg):
    global fun

    if frame.f_code.co_filename == '/path/to/module.py':
        if 'fun' in frame.f_globals:
            # The function has just been defined. Save it.
            fun = frame.f_globals['fun']
            # And replace it with our stub.
            frame.f_globals['fun'] = stub

            # Stop tracing the module execution.
            return None

    return wait_for_fun

sys.settrace(wait_for_fun)
import my_module

# Now fun() is available and we can test it.
fun(1, 2, 3)
# We can also put it again inside the module.
# This is important if other functions in the module need it.
my_module.fun = fun
```

This code can be improved in many ways, but it does its job.

Comment: Can you actually write the code to import for the minimal example in the original question?

Comment: @celebisait: yeah, just give me a few minutes, it's late here :)

Answer (score -3):

maybe if you just want to import the fun () function from submission.py try

> > > from submission import fun

## To perform the function of fun, you must include the fun module

> > > submission.fun()

or if you want to make it easier when calling the fun () function, give it a try
from submission import fun as FUN

FUN ()

Comment: First, if you import as `form submission import fun`, then you can only access the `fun` function with `fun()` directly. Not with `submission.fun()`. Second, this does not answer the question because it does not explain how to import the submission module without executing some statement therein.